# How search in arrays inside a array (MongoDB and PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I got this structure from my MongoDB database and i'd like to search by street name:

http://pastebin.com/JGf30bMq

As tou can see, it has arrays inside arrays...
How can i build the query?

Comment: Please add your structure to the question not by a link.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to search in your array using the dot collection. This code is not tested, but should give you a pointer where to go looking:

```
db.collection.find({ "addresses.street": "name_of_the_street_to_search"});
```

Not sure if this is what you mean though, maybe you could be a little more specific?

Comment: Thanks friend. Worked!

Answer (score 1):

You need to get street address. So, most probably your query will be :

```
db.collection.find({ "addresses.street": "your_desire_street"});
```